# pytorch runs much slower than tensorflow even for a shallow CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

The input data is an EEG data which was converted into PSD. And its shape is **[103600, 59, 51]**, where 103600 is the number of samples, i.e. the total samples for an epoch. The data was loaded into memory.

And the model I used is very simple, however, the time required **for training an epoch was 50s with pytorch 0.4 and a GTX 1080**. However, the time for val set interface was 0.3s.

I also tested this model using **tensorflow 1.2.0 the time was 8s**. I have no idea if I got it wrong.

So I made some test. This img shows the time for runing.

[image]

where
***time_to_tensor*** is the time for `inputs, targets = torch.tensor(inputs, dtype=torch.float), torch.tensor(targets, dtype=torch.int64)`

***time_to_cuda*** for `inputs, targets = inputs.to(self.device), targets.to(self.device)`

***time_to_model*** for `out = self.model(inputs)`

***time_criterion for*** `loss = self.criterion(out, targets)`

***time_backward*** for `self.optimizer.step()`

It seems the operation for tensor.to(self.device) (or tensor.cuda()) wasted much time. So *I tried to move the data to GPU at once*, using

```
self.X_train = torch.tensor(self.X_train, dtype=torch.float).to(self.device)
self.y_train = torch.tensor(self.y_train, dtype=torch.int64).to(self.device)
```

and commented

```
inputs, targets = torch.tensor(inputs, dtype=torch.float), torch.tensor(targets, dtype=torch.int64)
inputs, targets = inputs.to(self.device), targets.to(self.device)
```

However I got the running time in the following img.
[image]
The time required for an epoch still was about 50s, and time for each operation changed. I am confused.

Could someone help me to find the problem? Thanks.

Code was here.

## It's the model I used

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class TxtCNN4(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, n_classes=6, time_steps=59, psd_lenght=51, filter_numbers=128):
        super(TxtCNN4, self).__init__()
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.time_steps = time_steps
        self.psd_lenght = psd_lenght
        self.filters = filter_numbers

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=self.filters//2, 
                                kernel_size=(3, psd_lenght), stride=1, padding=0, bias=False)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(self.filters//2, momentum=0.05)
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(self.time_steps - 3 + 1, 1))

        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=self.filters//2, out_channels=self.filters,
                                    kernel_size=(3, 1), stride=1, padding=0, bias=False)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(self.filters, momentum=0.05)
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(self.time_steps - 5 + 1, 1))

        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=self.filters, out_channels=self.filters,
                                    kernel_size=(3, 1), stride=1, padding=0, bias=False)
        self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(self.filters, momentum=0.05)
        self.pool3 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(self.time_steps - 7 + 1, 1))

        self.fc = nn.Linear(in_features=2*self.filters+self.filters//2, out_features=128)
        self.cls = nn.Linear(in_features=128, out_features=self.n_classes)
        self.criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=None)

    def forward(self, inputs):
        inputs = inputs.view(-1, self.time_steps, self.psd_lenght, 1)
        inputs = inputs.permute(0, 3, 1, 2)
        conv1 = F.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(inputs)), inplace=True)
        conv2 = F.relu(self.bn2(self.conv2(conv1)), inplace=True)
        conv3 = F.relu(self.bn3(self.conv3(conv2)), inplace=True)

        x = torch.cat((self.pool1(conv1), self.pool2(conv2), self.pool3(conv3)), dim=1)
        x = x.view(-1, 2*self.filters+self.filters//2)
        x = F.dropout(x, p=0.5, training=self.training)
        x = F.relu(self.fc(x), inplace=True)
        x = self.cls(x)

        return x
```

## It's the main python file for traning the model

```
file_path = '/mnt/disk2/wy/SLEEP_EDF/'

batch_size = 32*4*2
dropout_rate = 0.5
nb_classes = 5
max_epochs = 100
early_stop_epoch = 10

learning_rate = 1e-3

model_type='TxtCNN4'
filter_numbers = 128

fs = 100    # Sample frequence
n_Channels = 2
n_Samples = 30*100

load_flag = False
model_path = ''

def iterate_minibatches(inputs, targets, batchsize, shuffle=False):
    input_len = inputs.shape[0]
    assert input_len == len(targets)

    if shuffle:
        indices = np.arange(input_len)  
        np.random.shuffle(indices)
    for start_idx in range(0, input_len, batchsize):
        if shuffle:
            excerpt = indices[start_idx:start_idx + batchsize]
        else:
            excerpt = slice(start_idx, start_idx + batchsize)

class Trainer():

    def __init__(self, X_inputs, labels, fold, subj_id, log_path, model_type=model_type, args=None):
        self.subj_id = subj_id
        self.model_type = model_type
        self.writer_root_path = os.path.abspath(
                                os.path.join(
                                    os.path.curdir,
                                    log_path+'_'+model_type,
                                    model_type + '_' + str(subj_id)))
        self.train_writer = SummaryWriter(os.path.join(self.writer_root_path, 'train'))
        self.val_writer = SummaryWriter(os.path.join(self.writer_root_path, 'val'))
        self.test_writer = SummaryWriter(os.path.join(self.writer_root_path, 'test'))

        self.curr_epcoh = 0
        self.curr_iter = 0

        self.train_end_flag = False

        (self.X_train, self.y_train), (self.X_val, self.y_val), (self.X_test, self.y_test) = reformatInput(X_inputs, labels, fold)
        print('Test set label and BiLi:\t', np.unique(self.y_test, return_counts=True))
        # normalization between all data
        X_mean = self.X_train.mean()
        X_std = self.X_train.std()
        self.X_train = (self.X_train - X_mean)/X_std
        self.X_val = (self.X_val - X_mean)/X_std
        self.X_test = (self.X_test - X_mean)/X_std


        if model_type == 'TxtCNN4':
            model = TxtCNN4()
        else:
            model = DeepSleepNet()
        self.device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
        self.model = model.to(self.device)
        self.criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=None)

        # self.X_train = torch.tensor(self.X_train, dtype=torch.float).to(self.device)
        # self.y_train = torch.tensor(self.y_train, dtype=torch.int64).to(self.device)

        self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)


    def train(self, epoch):
        train_loss = AvgMeter()
        train_acc = AvgMeter()
        start_time = time.time()

        time_to_tensor = 0
        time_to_cuda = 0
        time_model = 0
        time_criterion = 0
        time_backward = 0
        time_step = 0
        time_writer = 0
        self.curr_epcoh = epoch
        self.model.train()
        for (inputs, targets) in iterate_minibatches(self.X_train, self.y_train, batch_size, shuffle=False):
            self.curr_iter += 1
            time_1 = time.time()
            inputs, targets = torch.tensor(inputs, dtype=torch.float), torch.tensor(targets, dtype=torch.int64)  # dtype=torch.int64
            time_to_tensor += (time.time() - time_1)
            time_1 = time.time()
            inputs, targets = inputs.to(self.device), targets.to(self.device)
            time_to_cuda += (time.time() - time_1)

            # zero the parameter gradients
            self.optimizer.zero_grad()

            # forward + backward + optimize
            time_1 = time.time()
            out = self.model(inputs)
            time_model += (time.time() - time_1)

            time_1 = time.time()
            loss = self.criterion(out, targets)
            time_criterion += (time.time() - time_1)

            time_1 = time.time()
            loss.backward()
            time_backward += (time.time() - time_1)

            time_1 = time.time()
            self.optimizer.step()
            time_step += (time.time() - time_1)

            if self.curr_iter % 20 == 0:
                time_1 = time.time()
                pred = out.max(dim=1)[1].cpu().numpy()
                gt = targets.cpu().numpy()
                acc = np.mean(pred==gt)
                _loss = loss.detach().cpu().numpy()
                train_acc.update(acc)
                train_loss.update(_loss)

                self.train_writer.add_scalar('learning_rate', curr_lr, self.curr_iter)
                self.train_writer.add_scalar('acc', acc, self.curr_iter)
                self.train_writer.add_scalar('loss', _loss, self.curr_iter)
                time_writer += (time.time() - time_1)


        fmt_str = "Train\tEpoch [{:d}/{:d}]  train_Loss: {:.4f}\ttrain_Acc: {:.2f}\tTime per Epoch: {:.4f}"
        print_str = fmt_str.format(self.curr_epcoh,
                                    max_epochs,
                                    train_loss.avg, 
                                    train_acc.avg*100, 
                                    time.time()-start_time)
        print(print_str)
        print('time_to_tensor: ',time_to_tensor)
        print('time_to_cuda: ',time_to_cuda)
        print('time_model: ',time_model)
        print('time_criterion: ',time_criterion)
        print('time_backward: ',time_backward)
        print('time_step: ',time_step)
        print('time_writer: ',time_writer)
        print(len(self.y_train))
        train_acc.reset()
        train_loss.reset()

    def validation(self):
        self.model.eval()
        with torch.no_grad():
            # val set
            loss_gather = AvgMeter()
            pred_gather = PreGather()
            tran_time = 0
            for (inputs, targets) in iterate_minibatches(self.X_val, self.y_val, batch_size, shuffle=False):
                time_1 = time.time()
                inputs, targets = torch.tensor(inputs, dtype=torch.float), torch.tensor(targets, dtype=torch.int64)  # dtype=torch.int64
                inputs, targets = inputs.to(self.device), targets.to(self.device)
                tran_time += (time.time() - time_1)

                out = self.model(inputs)
                _loss = self.criterion(out, targets).detach().cpu().numpy()
                pred = out.max(dim=1)[1].cpu().numpy()
                loss_gather.update(_loss)
                pred_gather.update(pred)


            val_loss = loss_gather.avg
            pred = pred_gather.pred
            val_acc = np.mean(pred==self.y_val)
            val_kappa = cohen_kappa_score(self.y_val, pred)
            val_BCA = recall_score(self.y_val, pred, average='macro')
            loss_gather.reset()
            pred_gather.reset()

            # Then we print the results for this epoch:
            fmt_str = "VAL \tEpoch [{:d}/{:d}]  val_Loss: {:.4f}\tval_Acc: {:.2f}\tval_kappa: {:.2f}\tval_BCA: {:.2f}"
            print_str = fmt_str.format(self.curr_epcoh,
                                        max_epochs,
                                        val_loss,
                                        val_acc*100,
                                        val_kappa*100,
                                        val_BCA*100)
            print(print_str)
            print(tran_time)
            print(len(self.y_val))
            self.val_writer.add_scalar('acc', val_acc, self.curr_iter)
            self.val_writer.add_scalar('loss', val_loss, self.curr_iter)
            self.val_writer.add_scalar('kappa', val_kappa, self.curr_iter)
            self.val_writer.add_scalar('bca', val_BCA, self.curr_iter)


def train_all_subject(num_epochs=max_epochs, log_path=None):
    # Leave-Subject-Out cross validation
    subj_nums, fold_pairs, EEGs, labels = load_data(file_path, subj_nums=38, channel=1)  
    for subj_id in range(subj_nums):
        print('The subj_id', subj_id, '\t\t Training the ' + model_type + ' Model...')
        trainer = Trainer(EEGs, labels, fold_pairs[subj_id], subj_id, log_path)
        for epoch in range(trainer.curr_epcoh, max_epochs):
            if trainer.train_end_flag is False:
                trainer.train(epoch)
                trainer.validation()
                print('-'*50)
            else:
                break
```

Comment: It would be easier to respond on this if you would use generated training data for this test, so that someone else would be able to reproduce the results in order to track down potential inefficiencies. Without being able to test it is difficult to say. That said, I wonder why time for backward and step are really low in the first picture, but extremely high in the second picture. That is a bit weird. You may also try `torch.tensor(..., device=device)` as this is generally (sometimes *much*) faster than using `.to(device)`. No detour over CPU memory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It might be hard to generate suitable data, and more code is needed to add. Actually, I also tried torch.tensor(..., device=self.device). There is no essential difference in the training time required.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem recently and filed an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/25821

Comment: Have you tried setting torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = True ?